# How do you change the background colour on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to change the background colour of my webpage on scroll using IntersectionObserver- this is the code I have so far:

```js
const callback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        style.backgroundColor = entry.target.getAttribute('data-color');
      }
    });
  };
  
  const changes = document.querySelectorAll('.change');

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);

  changes.forEach(change => {
    observer.observe(change);
});
```

I would like to have it change colour when the viewer scrolls to a div, possibly using something like

```html
<div id= "indiaText" class="change" data-color="orange">
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can achieve this? I have also tried $(window).scroll(function() {  however I only get an error using this method. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.

The only real problem was that the `style.backgroundColor =` line was throwing an exception because `style` wasn't declared/defined. i changed it to `document.body.style.backgroundColor`.

I tweaked a couple of other things, but these aren't critical:

- i added an options argument `{ threshold: .5 }` to the IntersectionObserver so the color change doesn't occur until the target div is 50% on screen.
- i added a css transition on `body` just to soften the color change.

```js
const callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = entry.target.dataset.color;
    }
  });
};

const changes = document.querySelectorAll('.change');

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, { threshold: .5 });

changes.forEach(change => {
  observer.observe(change);
});
```

```css
body {
 transition: .5s background-color;
}

.change {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="change" data-color="orange">orange</div>
<div class="change" data-color="blue">blue</div>
<div class="change" data-color="lavender">lavender</div>
<div class="change" data-color="orange">orange</div>
<div class="change" data-color="blue">blue</div>
<div class="change" data-color="lavender">lavender</div>
<div class="change" data-color="orange">orange</div>
<div class="change" data-color="blue">blue</div>
<div class="change" data-color="lavender">lavender</div>
<div class="change" data-color="orange">orange</div>
<div class="change" data-color="blue">blue</div>
<div class="change" data-color="lavender">lavender</div>
<div class="change" data-color="orange">orange</div>
<div class="change" data-color="blue">blue</div>
<div class="change" data-color="lavender">lavender</div>
<div class="change" data-color="orange">orange</div>
<div class="change" data-color="blue">blue</div>
<div class="change" data-color="lavender">lavender</div>
<div class="change" data-color="orange">orange</div>
<div class="change" data-color="blue">blue</div>
<div class="change" data-color="lavender">lavender</div>
<div class="change" data-color="orange">orange</div>
<div class="change" data-color="blue">blue</div>
<div class="change" data-color="lavender">lavender</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update the callback function:

```
if (entry.isIntersecting) {

 document.body.style.background = entry.target.getAttribute('data-color');

 //to change the background of the div
 // entry.target.style.background = entry.target.getAttribute('data-color');
 
 }
```

Comment: This sets the background of the div, not the background of the page.

Comment: Then we can use document.body.style.background = entry.target.getAttribute('data-color');